# Importing bulk products in saleor

Tags: python, django, graphql, saleor

I am new to saleor. Iam trying to find a solution for importing bulk products. I have 100+ products to insert at a time.
Is there any option to import products in a csv format.
I'd really appreciate if someone can help point me in the right direction.

tried with ProductBulkCreate mutation but unable to perform the import successfully. Iam expecting more than 100 products will importing in a single request

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `ProductBulkCreate`?

Comment: @sruthi can you added your approach lines of code